# how to check if the enddate is after the startdate in a zend form

Tags: zend-framework, forms, validation

I have a zend form with a start- and an endate.

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->setName($this->formName)
     ->setMethod('post');

$feStartdate = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('startdate');
$feEnddate = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('enddate');

$form->addElement($feStartDate)
     ->addElement($feEndDate)
     ->addElement('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
```

I assume I must write a custom validator for to check this.
How would this custom validator look like and how can I call it?
I assume something like

```
$feEnddate->addValidator('dateComesAfter', $feStartDate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, [custom validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html), combined with Zend_Date::isLater() would be the way to go.

Comment: I assume the validator should be attached to the enddate. In the function isValid($value) in the validator the $value is the value of the enddate. How do I get the value of the startdate in the validator?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - didn't get the email when you responded.

yes - you can add it to the enddate, and in the isValid($value, $context) function, you want to use $context['field_name'] to access the field you want to compare to.  To abstract the validator - you would set the field name to compare to in the constructor.

Constructor would be :

.. construct($fieldName, $fieldTitle) ..

and in isValid($value, $context = null) - you have:

$otherFieldValue = $context[$this->_otherFieldName];

Obviously, this is a rudimentary example, but I hope it illustrates how you can do it.